# Authenticating with Django REST Framework returns 405

Tags: django, sencha-touch, django-rest-framework

I have successfully setup `TokenAuthentication` and generated tokens which are sucessfully received by the user upon authentication. Unfortunately i am unable to send the token to the API without error ([DRF TokenAuthentication](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication)). The token is hardcoded for test and im running with djangos `runserver`. I see from the response that only `POST` and `OPTIONS` is allowed, but i can `curl` without any problems:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth -H 'Authorization: Token a83ff8dabb7fc7b800d381fd3994dfe2051cc0c2'
```

**The implementation**

controller/Login.js:

```
reSignInCommand: function (aToken) {
    var me = this;

 Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/',
    method: 'GET',
    disableCaching: false,
    timeout: 10000, 
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Token a83ff8dabb7fc7b800d381fd3994dfe2051cc0c2'
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        console.log("failure");
    }
});
```

api/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token'),
)
```

Debug:

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED

Request headers:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:da,zh;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Authorization:Token a83ff8dabb7fc7b800d381fd3994dfe2051cc0c2
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
Origin:http://127.0.0.1
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://127.0.0.1/sencha/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36

Response headers:
HTTP/1.0 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
Date: Fri, 20 Dec 2013 10:19:50 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5
Vary: Accept, Cookie
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
```

Comment: Can you ``curl`` to ``http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/`` (see the trailing slash)?

Comment: This means, that you can curl only to ``http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth``, not ``http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/``. Django adds trailing ``/`` through redirection if its missing.

Comment: If i remove the last backslash i get  `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth. The request was redirected to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight. ` its worth mentioning that i have enabled CORS: `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` in  `settings.py`

Comment: **Add missing slash** to ``curl`` URL and show the result.

Comment: `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/` =>                                                                     
`{"detail": "Method 'GET' not allowed."}% `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`curl` response is same as AJAX response. `curl` response returned 301 status code instead of 405 because you used different URL (which had no trailing slash).

The problem is that you can only **POST** to `/api-token-auth/` URL, **GET** method is not implemented.

As the Django REST framework [API token authentication docs](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication) say, use-case is this:

1. You have to POST `username` and `password` to `/api-token-auth/` - to obtain an authentication token.
2. To access URL which requires authentication you have to include the token in the Authorization HTTP header. This means you have to test if token authentication works on URL which requires authentication.

> Authentication is always run at the very start of the view, before the permission and throttling checks occur, and before any other code is allowed to proceed.

You do not have to verify the token, because its done for you. If token provided in the HTTP header is valid request will have extra objects:

- **request.user** will be a Django User instance.
- **request.auth** will be a rest_framework.authtoken.models.BasicToken instance.

Comment: I have realised that, but how do i solve the problem?

Comment: I found the problem: you have to use POST, because /api-token-auth/ does not handle GET requests.

Comment: Maybe i am understanding something, but i should be able to authenticate with my token, when i try to do this as shown in my example, with `POST` instead of  `GET` i just get a `400 BAD REQUEST` instead.

Comment: Its ``BAD REQUEST`` because you use ``/api-token-auth/`` for bad purpose. You have to post ``username`` and ``password`` to get authentication token, instead of simply adding token to the header.

Comment: But when i have the token i should be able to send it for verification? Similar to the curl example in the `TokenAuthentication` section?

Comment: I want to be able to relogin by only using the token, if the user has accidently gone back to the login page again, as i understand it should be possible to only send the token for verification according to their own example. But maybe it require a extra function that verifies the token instead?

Comment: oh I have an insight! I just went down and typed some text.